# I made basketball program using Java that runs on console

Tags: java, game, console

I made a simple console basketball game using Java.

```
/*
 * Java Basketball
 * by Clint
 * 2020.07.08 | 3:59AM
 * This Java program let's the player play basketball in console.
 */
 
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Basketball {

    static String[] shoot = {"1 POINT!", "2 POINTS!", "3 POINTS!", "MISSED!"};
    static String player;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO JAVA CONSOLE BASKETBALL\n" +
                "how to play:\n" +
                "press \"s\" or type \"shoot\" to shoot the basketball.\n");
                
        while (true) {
            shootBall();
        }
    }

    public static void shootBall() {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int shot = random.nextInt(shoot.length);
        System.out.print("SHOOT: ");
        player = scanner.nextLine();
        
        switch (player) {
            case "s", "S", "shoot", "Shoot", "SHOOT" -> System.out.println(shoot[shot] + "\n");
            default -> System.out.println("SHOOT THE BALL PROPERLY.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

ps: ik that there's `while (true)` in my code, but it's the thing that I know so far that keeps the programme running. I'm open for suggestions on how to improve my coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Descriptive variable names

You have this:

```
player = scanner.nextLine();
```

Does the input reflect a player?

I think a more descriptive name would be `playerInput`. That makes the switch more readable as well.

### Make methods do one thing (single responsibility principle)

Your `shootBall` method does three things: asking for input, calculating the result, and printing the result. Ideally this would be split up:

- `private String getInput()`
- `private String shootBall(String input)`
- `private String printResult(String result)`

This makes it easier to change the implementation of a responsibility and easier to read the logic of your program.

The main while loop would become

```
while(true) {
    String input = getInput();
    String result = shootBall(input);
    printResult(result);
}
```

This makes it easier for coding some exit value as well;

```
while (true) {
    String input = getInput();
    if (input.equals("QUIT"))
      break;
    String result = shootBall(input);
    printResult(result);
}
```

Or, if you don't like the `while-true-break`

```
String input;
while (!(input = getInput()).equals("QUIT")) {
    printResult(shootBall(input));
}
```

Comment: `if (input.equals("QUIT"))` - i thought you meant: `if(isQuitCommand(input))` ... nice answer +1

Comment: @MartinFrank yes, good suggestion!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I made different methods for different parts of the program: https://pastebin.com/WfGrQtdV, how was it?

Comment: You should look into passing variables as method parameters :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need one instance of `Random` and `Scanner` for the whole programm. Especially creating new instances of `Scanner` is bad, because it locks resources, that you never free by closing it.

For the `switch` you are unnecessarily using the new expression syntax which is used when you want to return a value which you don't. The more conventional syntax would be:

```
switch (player) {
  case "s", "S", "shoot", "Shoot", "SHOOT":
    System.out.println(shoot[shot] + "\n");
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("SHOOT THE BALL PROPERLY.\n");
    break;
}
```